# Why does Microsoft Authenticator app ask me to choose a number?

Tags: multi-factor

I've got the Microsoft Authenticator app installed on my Google Pixel phone. When I sign into a Microsoft site, the site shows me a two-digit number (e.g. 34) and the app on my phone asks me to choose the matching number from three similar two-digit numbers (e.g. 28, 34 and 37).

Once I've picked the matching number (34), the site login continues.

What's the threat model here? What attacks is this protecting me from that a simple Yes/No prompt on the phone (as Google uses) wouldn't?

Comment: That has to do with being offline: a prompt requires internet, but once once the app and the server are synchronized, they can both independently generating numbers as rolling codes, based on the time.

Comment: These aren't rolling (TOTP) codes, as far as I can tell. They're only two digits, and the web site waits for me to pick one *on the phone*.

Comment: Ah my bad, I read that too quickly. I'm not too sure, but it might be preventing something like an overlay attack: https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/cyberpedia/android-toast-overlay-attack

Comment: It's not really about preventing phishing. It's to prevent someone that has your password (or other authenticator) from requesting a 2FA proof for a seperate session at the same time as you're about to log in. Otherwise all an attacker has to do is try a bunch of times and eventually you'll just say screw it and hit 'ok'.

Answer (score 4):

This is a way of closing the loop by ensuring that the phone owner knows the information provided by the website. In principle, it seems to add little benefit since, if you are entering your credentials on a phishing site, and that site is using your credentials to log in, it could channel back the presented number that you need to provide on the phone. (It would be a little harder than doing so asynchronously, but not that much)

This is different than eg. a prompt from a bank, where presenting/asking the amount to be transferred makes sense to avoid an attack where the amount of the transaction had been tampered with.

If an attacker knew your credentials and you always logged in at the same hour, this would prevent that an attacker logged in at the same time as you and you inadvertently gave access to them, but it seems extremely hard (maybe if you are aand the attacker was viewing your login screen?). Also, I'm not sure how do either Microsoft or Google react when receiving two concurrent login requests for the same account, they could deny both of them in that case.

A scenario where this would matter is if the phone bearer is different than the one logging in, so a number-choosing forces that there is a communication from the one logging in to the bearer, while a Yes/No question could be approved without paying much attention (*oh sure, this must be Bob*).

My suspicion is that this is implemented as a defensive approach, in order to avoid that people get used to always tap Yes and approve everything, perhaps even before realizing what they are doing. The number-choosing method forces the user to be aware of the actual application that is requesting access at this point.

Finally, even if this is only slightly more secure than a Yes/No question, its cost is so low that it makes sense that they implemented this.

Comment: I saw an anecdote about this the other day: someone got hacked because a quite-senior-but-IT-naive just kept pressing "Yes". They'd not told him to only do that _when he was trying to log in_, so he did it every time it came up.

By prompting with numbers, you close that loop.